# Rendering SVG using wxPython printing facilities

Tags: printing, svg, wxpython

I'm using wxPython printing facilities to print a simple html page and it worked fine until now.

The code is very simple and is this one:

```
printout = wx.html.HtmlPrintout("Printing")
printout.SetHtmlText(document)
```

"document" is an html document. Now in the html document I would like to add a SVG image.
So, on top of the new html document there is:

```
<img src="path_to_my_svg_image" />
```

When I try to print, wxPython gives me a popup error with message
"No handler found for image type"

So I think SVG is not supported by wxPython.

In internet I found
https://code.google.com/p/wxpsvg/
or
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyWxSVG/0.3

but what I need to is not to print a svg image but an html document with a svg image and as far as I have understood they do not fit for my purposes.

Did anyone have the same problems as mine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [here](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/src/common/imagall.cpp), the underlying wxWidgets library doesn't know how to handle SVG images:

```
void wxInitAllImageHandlers()
{
#if wxUSE_LIBPNG
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxPNGHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_LIBJPEG
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxJPEGHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_LIBTIFF
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxTIFFHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_GIF
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxGIFHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_PNM
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxPNMHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_PCX
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxPCXHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_IFF
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxIFFHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_ICO_CUR
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxICOHandler );
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxCURHandler );
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxANIHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_TGA
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxTGAHandler );
#endif
#if wxUSE_XPM
  wxImage::AddHandler( new wxXPMHandler );
#endif
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to call AddHandler from Python (with a suitable wxSVGHandler of course), but if you need to use wx print facilities I'd try that way